# Delete some folder from SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I want to Delete some folder from SVN from my machine and that is possible but that also should delete from someone else machine. and he can never get that folder by previous version. Can this possible?

Answer (score 1):

When you delete versioned items, they will be removed from other users' working copies on their next `svn update` unless there are uncommitted changes in their working copies. But if they've copied the content elsewhere, you can't remove that from their computers.

If you want to remove something from the repository history *completely*, you'll have to dump the repository contents, filter out what you want removed, then reload the repository. This is a very disruptive event and depending upon your repository size, may be very time-consuming. The process for doing so is [documented in the Subversion FAQ](https://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#removal) but before doing it, consider just how critical it is that this content be removed.